# Google Chrome Crashes in Ubuntu 16.04 (Mate and LTS both)

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome Crashes after a clean installation of ubuntu 16.04 and ubuntu mate 16.04 I have to restart the machine then it works for some time and then again the same it hangs only google chrome freezes remaining all applications run smoothly.

Now is it OS bug problem or hardware problem? its really annoying any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: *Depends* on what are your hardware specification! can you update you question with specs

Comment: Can you start it from the terminal and post the crash log from the terminal output?

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Any additional extensions installed into Chrome?